# Difference between a simple reflex and a model-based reflex agents in AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Among the intelligent agent types in AI, there is simple-reflex and model-based-reflex. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `simple-reflex agent` selects actions based on the agents **current perception** of the world and not based on past perceptions

A `model-based-reflex agent` is made to deal with partial accessibility; they do this by keeping track of the part of the world it can see now. It does this by **keeping an internal state that depends on what it has seen before** so it holds information on the unobserved aspects of the current state.

The former only base its analysis on current states while the latter takes account of past events

Answer (score 0):

Simplex Reflex Agent is the simplest kind of agent. These agents selects actions on the basis of the current percept , ignoring the rest of the percept history. It can handle a fully observation environment.

Model based reflex agents slects actions selects actions on the basis of percept history. It can handle a partial observation environment.